# How to show videos frame by frame (with key presses) with python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, video

I am trying to open a video file and play it frame by frame using key presses. So it would open and show a single frame indefinitely until a particular key is pressed and then it would switch to the next frame.

I'm using Python 3 and OpenCV. This is the first time I am using OpenCV so any corrections/recommendations are welcome.

The code below works in the sense that it shows the video one frame at a time but not only when I press <kbd>k</kbd> but with any key press and it ignores the <kbd>q</kbd> to exit.

```
import cv2
import os


def play_video(folder):
    # load video capture from file
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(folder, "Field.mp4"))
    # window name and size
    cv2.namedWindow("video", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    while video.isOpened():
        # Read video capture
        ret, frame = video.read()
        # Display each frame
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)
        # show one frame at a time
        cv2.waitKey(00) == ord('k')
        # Quit when 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
    # Release capture object
    video.release()
    # Exit and distroy all windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


play_video("bb-eye-s001")
```

I would like to press a specific key to move forward (one to move back too, but that might be for another question) and be able to press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `cv2.waitKey(00) == ord('k')` condition you have is never tested. Effectively, that line computes `True` or `False`, then throws it away.
What you want it to stop until the user presses either `'q'` or `'k'`:

```
while video.isOpened():
    # Read video capture
    ret, frame = video.read()
    # Display each frame
    cv2.imshow("video", frame)
    # show one frame at a time
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    while key not in [ord('q'), ord('k')]:
        key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    # Quit when 'q' is pressed
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution that has better control flow, a single call to `waitKey`, "event handler" code blocks, proper error checking on the VideoCapture object.

```py
...
assert video.isOpened()

cv.namedWindow("video", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while True:
    key = cv.waitKeyEx(0) # waitKeyEx also reads arrow keys

    if key == ord('k'):
        (ret, frame) = video.read()
        if not ret: break
        cv.imshow("video", frame)
    
    elif key == ord('q'):
        break

    else:
        print(f"unknown key code 0x{key:02x}")

cv.destroyWindow("video")
...
```